# Program to find sum and if entered 'y' then repeat the process using do while loop

Tags: c, string, do-while

Here a print message "Do you want to run again?" is asked, if we enter "y" then program will repeat.

**I tried this code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    char ch;
    ch = 'y';
    printf("enter 1st and 2nd no.");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    {
        c = a + b;
        printf("%d", c);
        printf("Do you want to run again?");
        scanf("%s", &ch);
    }
    while(ch == 'y')
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a do-while.  It's a block, followed by an unrelated `while` whose body is `return 0;` (which makes no sense).  You need to add the keyword `do` in front of the block, and a semicolon after the while, e.g. `do { ... } while (...);`

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you I got the answer as I am a noob and this is my first program using do while loop, I was not knowing the process properly, Thank you very much. If you want you can post your comment as answer

Comment: You may want to look at [Sum and Average with Dynamic Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723670/sum-and-average-with-dynamic-array/58726453#58726453) for how to simplify handling the `'Y'` or `'y'` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a do-while loop:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    char ch;

    do {
        printf("enter 1st and 2nd number: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        c = a + b;
        printf("%d\n", c);
        printf("Do you want to run again?: ");
        scanf("%s",&ch);
    }
    while(ch=='y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&ch);` expect a pointer to store of _string_ longer than `""`. `char ch;` is too small for that

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a,b,c;
   char ch;

   do
   {
   printf("enter 1st and 2nd no.");
   scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
   c = a + b;
   printf("%d",c);
   printf("Do you want to run again?");
   scanf(" %c",&ch);
   }
   while(ch == 'y');
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes we can use ("%c",&ch) also here.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica but output is not coming with %c

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes it did work this time with space, Thank you.